# Scala: duplicate lists n times inside another list

Tags: scala, list

I have a list in scala and from that list I want to generate a list of lists in which each list will be duplicated n times.

I tried to use tabulate:

```
val list = orders.map(ord => List.tabulate(ord.quantity * ord.prod.tasks.size)(ord.prod.tasks))
```

But it gives me an error: [here](https://pastebin.com/RwJ3r3vB).

I tried to use `List.fill`, but it returns a `List[List[List[Task]]]`.

```
val list = orders.map(ord => List.fill(ord.quantity*ord.prod.tasks.size)(ord.prod.tasks))
```

Is there a way to make fill return a `List[List[Task]]`?

Comment: Did you try `flatMap`?

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val list = orders.flatMap(ord => List.fill(ord.quantity*ord.prod.tasks.size)(ord.prod.tasks))
```